# Очень долгий рестарт MySQL, почему?

Tags: mysql

При попытке рестарта демона MySQL сильно возрастает нагрузка на диск, отзывчивость падает, MySQL "задумывается" на несколько минут, потом без проблем перезапускается. Старт происходит нормально. Проверка таблиц не показывает проблем.

На сервере кроме MySQL ничего больше не запущено, swap пуст, запросов на MySQL сервер до и непосредственно в момент рестарта идёт относительно мало.

В чём причина, как ускорить рестарт? А то обновился пакет MySQL - накатил апдейт, рестартишь демон и получаешь даунтайм в несколько минут вместо (как хотелось бы) десятка-другого секунд.

ОС Ubutnu Server 14.04 LTS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если в момент, когда "MySQL задумался" после начала рестарта, посмотреть в его лог (что-нибудь вроде `/var/log/mysql/mysql.log`), там могут быть записи вида

```
[Note] InnoDB: Waiting for page_cleaner to finish flushing of buffer pool
```

Если при попытке рестарта или выключения MySQL-сервера приходится несколько минут ждать, а в лог падают такие сообщения - это значит, что `InnoDB` накопил очень много «грязных страниц» в буфере (т.е. в оперативной памяти) и занмается их сбросом на диск.

Чтобы уменьшить даунтайм при рестарте, можно перед ним принудительно инициировать сброс данных из буфера на диск с помощью команды (набирать в консоли MySQL)

```
set global innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct = 0;
```

Производительность MySQL на запросы `UPDATE`, однако, при этом упадёт. Но работать в таком режиме "без буфера" MySQL будет лишь несколько минут, пока Вы его не перезапустите, так что это не страшно.